# Google chrome is not firing onResult event on voice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition

Everything is working fine in this code except the result showing part after receiving any audio.Can someone tell me why this is not logging any value in console even after i speak in the headphone.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <div id="msg2"></div>
    <script>
        (function(){

            var reco = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            var msgid = document.getElementById('msg');

            reco.interimResults = true;

            reco.addEventListener('start',function(){
                msgid.innerHTML = 'Listening...';
            });
            reco.addEventListener('audiostart',function(){
                msgid.innerHTML = 'Recording...';
            });

            reco.start();

            reco.onresult = function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        })()
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Suggest you try https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html, on another machine.
It didn't work on my hardened corporate laptop, but did in my personal PC.
No idea how to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, SpeechRecognition() is a constructor which is not supported by most of the browers, if you are running it in firefox, it won't help. Try this code in chrome. Later on in console -> Search for result -> Expand the result tab -> Search something called transcript. There it is, your recorded text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="talk">Talk</button>
    <h3 class="content"></h3>
    <script>
       const btn = document.querySelector(".talk");
const content = document.querySelector(".content");

const SpeechRecognition =
  window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const myRecognition = new SpeechRecognition();
myRecognition.onstart = function() {
  console.log("voice is activated, you may now speak");
};

myRecognition.onresult = function() {
  console.log(event);
};

//adding eventListener

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  myRecognition.start();
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes i am running it in chrome,but it didn't worked for me. I tried your code as well. but the result is same, no output in console.

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/sbcodes/pen/pozZroe?editors=1000)   open this codepen in google chrome, hit button talk, press F12, speak "hello", wait for a moment until it return result. then expand "SpeechRecognitionEvent" -> expand "results" -> expand -> "0: SpeechRecognitionResult" and in that search something for transcript. "Hello" must be there.

Comment: yeah its working fine with active internet connection. But its not working with local server if you are not connected to internet. Can you tell me the reason ? @Suhem Bali

Answer (score 0):

Internet connection is required for working with speech recognition since the recorded speech must be fed through internet connection to a web service for processing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).